# How can I access the any property of the class?

Tags: flutter

I have an Expanded widget, inside of this widget I create new ingredients object after I want it to add a list of another class which takes Ingredients object, But when I try to use add function of the list, I face with an error below.. I guess it cant access the list of ingredients inside of the subCategories. Please help me.

```
Expanded(
                  flex: 40,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: ()async{
                            if(_ingredients.length==0){
                              Ingredient ingredient= Ingredient(ingredientName:"${items[index]}",dropDownValue: "Çay Kaşığı",ingredientAmount:null);
                              categoryModels[widget.subCategoryId].subCategoryModels[widget.subCategoryCardId].ingredients.add(ingredient);
                              addIngredient(ingredient,context);
                              _toggleCardHeight();
                              _toggleCardSize();
                              setState(() {

                              });
                            }
                            else{
                              var flag=0;
                              for(var i in _ingredients){
                                if(i.ingredientName==items[index]){
                                  flag=-1;
                                  var response= await showAlertDialog(context);
                                  if (response==false){
                                    setState(() {});
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              if(flag==0){
                                Ingredient ingredient=Ingredient(ingredientName:"${items[index]}",dropDownValue: "Çay Kaşığı",ingredientAmount: null);
                                categoryModels[widget.subCategoryId].subCategoryModels[widget.subCategoryCardId].ingredients.add(ingredient);
                                addIngredient(ingredient,context);
                                setState(() {});
                                }
                              }
                            },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                              border: Border.all(style:BorderStyle.solid,width: 1),
                              color: Colors.white54,

                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Text('${items[index]}',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

And here is the class that ı want to add ingredient to the list as an object.

```
class CategoryModel{
  CategoryModel(
    {
      this.categoryId,
      this.categoryImagePath,
      this.categoryName,
      this.categoryColor,
      this.subCategory
    });
  final SubCategoryModel subCategory;
  final Color categoryColor;
  final List<SubCategoryModel> subCategoryModels=[SubCategoryModel()];
  int categoryId;
  String categoryImagePath;
  String categoryName;

}
class SubCategoryModel{
  SubCategoryModel(
    {
      this.subCategoryId,
      this.subCategoryImagePath,
      this.subCategoryName,
      this.categoryColor,
      this.recipeId,
      this.ingredients,
      this.recipePhotoDir,
      this.recipeTextFromSpeechProcessing,
      this.recordedVoiceDir});

  final Color categoryColor;
  final double recipeId;
  int subCategoryId;
  String subCategoryImagePath;
  String subCategoryName;
  List<Ingredient> ingredients= [];
  String recipeTextFromSpeechProcessing;
  String recipePhotoDir;
  String recordedVoiceDir;
}
```

### ERROR

```
E/flutter ( 7266): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 7266): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7266): Tried calling: add(Instance of 'Ingredient')
```

can someıne help me? How can I handle with this issue.

Comment: Can we see the `addIngridient` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a list to `ingredients` member in your `SubCategoryModel` class and then use the `this` keyword to initialize it in your constructor. Since the `this` keyword refers to the current instance, `ingredients` will be null when you create its class.

You should replace `this` keyword with `List<Ingredient>`:

```
class SubCategoryModel {
  SubCategoryModel({
    this.subCategoryId,
    this.subCategoryImagePath,
    this.subCategoryName,
    this.categoryColor,
    this.recipeId,
    List<Ingredient> ingredients,
    this.recipePhotoDir,
    this.recipeTextFromSpeechProcessing,
    this.recordedVoiceDir,
  });

  final Color categoryColor;
  final double recipeId;
  int subCategoryId;
  String subCategoryImagePath;
  String subCategoryName;
  List<Ingredient> ingredients = [];
  String recipeTextFromSpeechProcessing;
  String recipePhotoDir;
  String recordedVoiceDir;
}
```